# How to determine the number of integer pairs $n_1,n_2$ such that $n_1+2n_2=n$, with $n,n_1,n_2=0,1,2,3,...$?

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic-functions

In the context of a Quantum Physics problem with degenerate energy levels, I need to find the number of different pairs of integers $(n_1,n_2)$ such that $n_1+2n_2$ gives the same value $n$, with $n,n_1,n_2=0,1,2,3,...$.

While this is easily feasible by studying the graph $n_1(n_2)=n-2n_2$, or with computer code, is there any straightforward way to determine it algebraically?

Comment: Do you want $n_1+n_2=n$ or $n_1+2n_2=n$?   Are these meant to be non-negative?  Strictly positive?

Comment: If you want non-negative, and you meant $2n_2$, then you just need $n_1$ to be of the same parity as $n$ and $0<n_1<n$..  if you just meant non-negative, then you have $0≤n_1≤n$.

Comment: As long as $2n_2\le n$, you have an unique $n_1$, so the number of solutions is just $\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor$

Comment: Please edit for clarity.  As it stands, the question in the header does not match the question in the body.

Comment: I meant $n_1+2n_2=n$ and $n,n_1,n_2$ non-negative integers. It is ok now.